# DatePicker control like in iPhone

Tags: html, ios, user-interface

I have a Wordpress website with a form built with Contact Form 7. It has a JQuery datepicker. In window and android its good but in iPhone its not looking like date picker in iphone.

[image: iPhone Datepicker]

Please suggest how can I solve this issues to work like iphone.

Comment: Can you elaborate more..

Comment: If I am doing <input  type="date"> the calender control is working fine in apple phones. But <input  type="date" is not working in IE and FF. Chrome and Opera its working fine. So If i am using any JQuery datepicker so <input  type="date"> is conflicting with it.